# How to Create Service Worker to Store Dynamic Content in Progressive Web App?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I develop a progressive web app with static content. It's working fine with static content, but whenever we try to fetch data dynamically from an MS SQL database, it's not working as expected. How can I get dynamic data from the MS SQL database and display it into a cached page or how to use the network only function? Do I need to make any change in the `service-worker.js` file to retrieve dynamic data?

service-worker.js :

```
var version = "1.0::";

var offlineResources = [
"/",
"style.css",
"image/logo.png",
"image/logo.jpg"
];

self.addEventListener("install", function(event) {
event.waitUntil(
    caches
        .open(version + "static")
        .then(function(cache) {
            cache.addAll(offlineResources);
        })
);
});

self.addEventListener("activate", function(event) {
event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keys) {
        return Promise.all(keys
            .filter(function (key) {
                return key.indexOf(version) !== 0;
            })
            .map(function (key) {
                return caches.delete(key);
            })
        );
    })
);
});

function isOfflineOrigin(origin) {
return origin === location.origin || origin.indexOf("netlify") !== -1;
}

self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
var request = event.request;
var url = new URL(request.url);

// Only worry about GET requests and certain domains
if (request.method !== "GET" || !isOfflineOrigin(url.origin)) {
    return;
}

// For HTML try the network first, fall back to the cache, and then
// finally the offline page
if (request.headers.get("Accept").indexOf("text/html") !== -1) {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(request)
            .then(function(response) {
                var copy = response.clone();
                caches.open(version + "pages")
                    .then(function(cache) {
                        cache.put(request, copy);
                    });
                return response;
            })
            .catch(function() {
                return caches.match(request)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        return response || caches.match("/offline/");
                    });
            })
    );
    return;
}

// For non-HTML requests look in the cache first, and fall back to
// the network
event.respondWith(
    caches.match(request)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(request);
        })
);
});
```

Comment: What is the path you think your request for dynamic content is taking?

Answer (score -1):

I can figure out that you are only caching static resources. `What about the dynamic content like the responses from a remote API or service?` 
You have to implement runtime caching for all your dynamic needs.

[sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) comes handy which gives flexibility to implement request handlers that handle runtime caching for remote or dynamic resources.

Comment: Thank you so much Chain. It will be very helpful, if any one can share the example. I want to do cache dynamic image. Images is going to change with new articles.